# der Schein und der Anschein

Tags: meaning, difference, synonym

Ich las die Definitionen vom Verb "scheinen" und seinen Derivaten bei thefreedictionary.com und es scheint, dass "der Schein" und "der Anschein" in Bezug auf den Bedeutungen "äußerer Eindruck" oder "etwas, das nicht so ist, wie es aussieht" Synonyme sind.

**Gibt es eine Unterschied zwischen "der Schein" und "der Anschein" oder sind sie Synonyme?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diese beiden Wörter sind sehr ähnlich. Hier zwei Beispiele, in denen beide tatsächlich gleichwertig eingesetzt werden können:

> Sein Angebot war nur dem Anschein nach gut. — Sein Angebot war nur dem Schein nach gut.
>
> Zum Schein ging sie darauf ein. — Zum Anschein ging sie darauf ein.

Tatsächlich werden diese beiden Ausdrücke aber praktisch immer in der linken Variante benutzt.

Meine Vermutung ist deshalb, dass der Gebrauch dieser beiden Wörter je nach dem Satzrhytmus schwankt: *Anschein* hat eine sehr prägnante zusätzliche Silbe, die oft auch noch stark betont wird. Im Gegensatz dazu lädt *Schein* zum Wegnuscheln geradezu ein.

Answer (score 2):

**Der Anschein** beschreibt in der Regel, wie etwas wahrgenommen wird. Dabei kann es möglich oder sogar wahrscheinlich sein, dass es genau so ist wie es denn Anschein hat.

> Es hat den Anschein als würde es bald regnen.
>   Dem Anschein nach hatte er die rote Ampel nicht gesehen.

**Der Schein** drückt im Gegensatz dazu aus, dass etwas eher anders ist als es wahrgenommen wird oder dass sogar mit Absicht **der Schein** erweckt wird, dass etwas anders aussieht als es wirklich ist.

> Mehr Schein als Sein.
>   Der Schein trügt.
>   Die Hochzeit wurde zum Schein abgehalten

Es gibt dann noch eine Menge zusammengesetzte Nomen, wo das auch zum Ausdruck kommt:

> Scheingesellschaft, Scheinselbständigkeit, Scheinprozess, Scheinbegräbnis

Answer (score 1):

Gehen Sie bitte auf dwds.de (Das Wortauskunftssystem zur deutschen Sprache)!
dort finden Sie praktisch für jeden Zweifelsfall richtige Deutung und Auslegung.

Kurz zu Ihrer Frage:
Ausgehend von guten Englischkenntnissen vereinfachend, neige ich den Unterschied zwischen "der Schein" und "der Anschein"  mit "the real thing" und "the maybe real thing" zu beschreiben.

Answer (score 1):

Der Schein heißt: Nicht die wirkliche Sache, sondern  nur seine "Licht", der Schein. Hierzu gehört scheinbar, das bedeutet nicht wirklich, es sieht nur so aus. Beispiel: Die scheinbare Bewegung der Sonne am Himmel.

Der Anschein heißt, es ist offensichtlich so, mit einer kleinen Irrtumsmöglichkeit. Hierzu gehört anscheinend, in der Bedeutung von offenbar oder offensichtlich.

Auch Muttersprachler verwechseln das und sagen scheinbar, wo anscheinend hingehört – vor allem im gesprochenen Wort. Man hört oft Sätze wie Ich bin hier scheinbar falsch. Gemein ist: Offensichtlich habe ich den Raum verwechselt. Die wörtliche Bedeutung aber ist/wäre: Auf den ersten Blick sieht es so aus, als wäre ich falsch, aber das ist nur scheinbar so. In Wirklichkeit hat alles seine Richtigkeit.

Erschwert wird diese Unterscheidung dadurch, dass die Redewendung "dem Anschein nach" auch zu "scheinbar" gehört und nicht etwa zu anscheinend. Logisch ist das alles nicht, es hat sich eben so entwickelt.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for my answer in English, but some type of explanations still exceed my skills in German.

*Der Schein* makes reference to how something looks, while *der Anschein*, although also makes reference to how something looks, it highlights in a special way the fact that this something ***appears*** to me as such. That is, der Schein expresses a fact, whereas der Anschein highlights the aspect of movement whereby that fact comes to be.
In Spanisch, for instance, der Anschein can also be translated as 
***el asomo*** which in English is something like the emergence. Der Schein, on the other hand, is just the apperance of something. 
Maybe consulting some philosophical books could help you understanding this difference in a much better way. Heidegger, for instance, explains this difference quite well in ***Sein und Zeit***. He says that the appearance of something - der Schein - hides the fact that for something to appear as something else, that is, in order for the apperance to be, such appearance must first come to be. **In this regard, every appearance entails an appearing.** **The former is der Schein, while the latter is der Anschein, although in regular language they are used as being the same.**

Comment: **der Schein expresses a fact* 
That is not true. _Der_ _Schein_ (in this meaning) mostly expresses what can be seen at the first glance, but it is definitively wrong. "Der Schein trügt". 
This meaning might be slightly doubtful in Der Schein and Es scheint so, but it is very clear in scheinbar. Scheinbar means not really.